# Android custom row layout in ListView with flexible height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-view

Hi I'm trying to create a row like this:
[image]

The row should be with flexible height and grow taller is the subtitle text is long.
The green view at the left should grow too to fill the entire height of the row.
The row height should be determined based only on the text (Title + Subtitle).

This is the layout that I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/is_in_range_view"
            android:layout_width="15dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#99CC00" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/subtitle"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <View
                style="@style/SeparatorLine"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this is the result I get:

[image]

Clearly the `fill_parent` value of the View's layout_height property is problematic, but this is exactly what I want!
I just want the row height will be based on the text, not the green view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you have the outer most LinearLayout? It seems redundant, since it's only child is another LinearLayout.

Comment: @Sam sorty you are right. Fixed. But it still dosen't solve it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, The problem is that I put the wrong value for `layout_height` in the inner `LinearLayout` that holds the two `TextView's`.
It was set to `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Once set to `wrap_content` everythig went fine.

The right layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/is_in_range_view"
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#99CC00" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="@string/subtitle"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <View
        style="@style/SeparatorLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```